# Help identifying sealed LEGO bag - 4 large yellow wheels, a windshield, a motor and a figure in an olive green shirt

Tags: set-identification

I bought this bag of LEGO bricks at a yard sale. It is sealed and I thought I could identify it by the number on that bag but got nothing. It appears to be a car and has 4 large yellow wheels, a windshield, a motor and a figure in an olive green shirt.

[image: 4 large yellow wheels, a windshield, a motor and a figure in an olive green shirt]

Can anyone help me in finding what set this goes to? It has the large number 3 followed by 627S0. I tried the QR codes and they didn't help either.

Comment: FYI: Bag numbers/QR codes are useless. They are only for production tracking at the Lego factories. Those numbers get re-used every couple of months/years and have no firm relationship with the set itself. It is even possible that a Lego set contains 2 identical bags with different numbers. (42055 even has 2 pairs of identical bags. In my own case 1 pair had identical numbers and the other pair had different numbers on the bags.)

Answer (score 11):

This bag is from :

[75940: Gallimimus and Pteranodon Breakout](https://brickset.com/sets/75940-1/Gallimimus-and-Pteranodon-Breakout)
[image]

keyparts:

- [Windscreen 8 x 4 x 2 with 2 Studs and Bar Handle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=21849&idColor=15#T=C&C=15)
- [Torso Female Jacket with Pockets over Sand Green Shirt with Green Stripes, Reddish Brown Belt Pattern / Olive Green Arms / Light Nougat Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb3126c01&idColor=155#T=C&C=155)